# How can a Scala compiler option be appended to scalacOptions in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I use sbt `0.10`.

I have the following setting in `.sbt` file:

```
scalacOptions += "-usejavacp"
```

The problem is that when the Scala compiler get executed and the `scalacOptions` is set:

```
[debug] Calling Scala compiler with arguments  (CompilerInterface):
[debug]         -usejavacp
[debug]         -d
[debug]         D:\project\target\scala-2.8.1.final\classes
[debug]         -bootclasspath
...
```

the `-usejavacp` parameter appears before the actual Scala jars that results in this error:

```
scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer does not take type parameters
```

Is there a way the parameter is appended and not prepended? I also tried the `++= Array("-usejavacp")` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Basic-Configuration), you'll see the following comment:

> `key += value` is equivalent to `key ~= (_ :+ value)` or `key <<= key(_ :+ value)`

Which, curiously enough, seems to contradict the order you are seeing. I think this is worth opening an issue about, and, meanwhile, you can play with the full syntax to see if you can accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, the list of custom scalac options, provided by the `scalacOptions` setting, are [prepended](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/v0.10.0/compile/CompilerArguments.scala#L15) to the options for controlling the classpath, output directory, and source files.

Presumably you are using `-usejavacp` to use the Scala compiler or interpreter programmatically. There is an entry for this in the [SBT FAQ](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/FAQ).